# Android - broken XML parsing example

Tags: android, xml, rss, android-contentprovider

Android SDK since release of API v. 11 contains XmlAdapter sample which is [also referenced from the official site](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/XmlAdapters/index.html). This sample appears now in at least 3 folders: android-11, android-12 and android-13. And it is broken. The main (but not only) problem it declares `android.content.XmlDocumentProvider` provider which is nowhere to be found including https://android.googlesource.com
There are also compilation problems in `Adapters.java`:

```
mContext cannot be resolved to a variable   line 973
mFrom cannot be resolved to a variable  line 938
mTo cannot be resolved to a variable    line 937
mTo cannot be resolved to a variable    line 939
```

There are few question related to this on `android-developers` but no answer. Did anyone managed to track this elusive `XmlDocumentProvider` and make the sample work?
And most importantly - dear Android team, can you ether fix the sample or pull it out?

Comment: I filled a bug at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19473

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing `XmlDocumentProvider` is now shipping with the sample in SDK 14 and the project compiles against SDK 8 and above. To run it successfully however, you must modify the manifest to point to the correct provider:

```
<provider android:name="com.example.android.xmladapters.XmlDocumentProvider"
       android:authorities="xmldocument" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides fixing the AndroidManifest.xml as pointed out by Jeff Gilfelt, you can also change the code XmlCursorAdapter class in Adapters.java (the file showing the errors)  like this:

```
/**
 * Implementation of a Cursor adapter defined in XML. This class is a thin wrapper
 * of a SimpleCursorAdapter. The main difference is the ability to handle CursorBinders.
 */
private static class XmlCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements ManagedAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private String mUri;
    private final String mSelection;
    private final String[] mSelectionArgs;
    private final String mSortOrder;
    private final int[] mTo;
    private final String[] mFrom;
    private final String[] mColumns;
    private final CursorBinder[] mBinders;
    private AsyncTask<Void,Void,Cursor> mLoadTask;



    XmlCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, String uri, String[] from, int[] to,
            String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder,
            HashMap<String, CursorBinder> binders) {

        super(context, layout, null, from, to);
        mContext = context;
        mUri = uri;
        mFrom = from;
        mTo = to;
        mSelection = selection;
        mSelectionArgs = selectionArgs;
        mSortOrder = sortOrder;
        mColumns = new String[from.length + 1];
        // This is mandatory in CursorAdapter
        mColumns[0] = "_id";
        System.arraycopy(from, 0, mColumns, 1, from.length);

        CursorBinder basic = new StringBinder(context, new IdentityTransformation(context));
        final int count = from.length;
        mBinders = new CursorBinder[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            CursorBinder binder = binders.get(from[i]);
            if (binder == null) binder = basic;
            mBinders[i] = binder;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        final int count = mTo.length;
        final int[] to = mTo;
        final CursorBinder[] binders = mBinders;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View v = view.findViewById(to[i]);
            if (v != null) {
                binders[i].bind(v, cursor, cursor.getColumnIndex(mFrom[i]));
            }
        }
    }
    ......
    ......
    ......
```

I got the answer from the code found here:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.1_r1/com/example/android/xmladapters/Adapters.java?av=f

Answer (score 0):

I got answer from Romain Guy, well sort of. The ticket that I opened yesterday now has a tag *Status: FutureRelease* which I suppose means that they will fix it in the next release. For the added reference here's link to the discussion on [android-developers](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/50002dafff5314)

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error and searched around, found the same question has been asked for many times. This is how I fixed it.

There is a `XmlDocumentProvider` class [I found](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/XmlAdapters/src/com/example/android/xmladapters/XmlDocumentProvider.html).

I copied the `XmlDocumentProvider.java` into the `XmlAdapter` project and revised the `AndroidManifest.xml` by replacing:

```
<provider android:name="android.content.XmlDocumentProvider"
       android:authorities="xmldocument" />
```

with:

```
<provider android:name="com.example.android.xmladapters.XmlDocumentProvider"
   android:authorities="xmldocument" />
```

Now I am able to get the `RssReaderActivity` working.